# Weblogic 12c deployment xml errors

Tags: weblogic, web-deployment, weblogic12c

I'm newbie to weblogic. I tried to deploy an application, but I got the following errors:

```
Unable to access the selected application.
Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected elements         
'filter-class@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee async-supported
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee init-param
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' 
instead of 'description@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' here in element     
filter
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null> 
problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4b: Element not allowed: 
description@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee in element init-param
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null> 
problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4b: Element not allowed: description
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee in element init-param
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null> 
problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected elements 'servlet-class
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee jsp-file
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee init-param
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee load-on-startup
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee enabled
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee async-supported
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee run-as
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee security-role-ref
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee multipart-config
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' instead of 'display-name
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' here in element servlet
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null> 
problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected elements 'servlet-class
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee jsp-file
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee init-param
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee load-on-startup
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee enabled
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee async-supported
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee run-as
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee security-role-ref
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee multipart-config
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' instead of 'display-name
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' here in element servlet
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null> 
problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected elements 'servlet-class
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee jsp-file
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee init-param
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee load-on-startup
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee enabled
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee async-supported
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee run-as
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee security-role-ref
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee multipart-config
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' instead of 'display-name
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' here in element servlet
@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null>
```

I tried to find weblogic.xml and web.xml, but there is just a war file. How can I modify the xxmls in the war?

Thanks for any responses. 
Allen

Comment: A war file is just like a jar file. You can unzip the contents with: 'jar -xvf webAppName.war'

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp hi, thanks for the answer. I know how to unzip this file, but Can I change the xml files and repack to war file, then  deploy the new one?

Comment: Yup, after you open up the war file you can modify whatever files you need inside it and then do something like 'jar cvf mywar.war .' to repackage it. Then you can deploy the new version

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp yeah, ok, thanks, but according to the errors I got, do you know why? I think there might be some definitions of tags are not right.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399401/deploy-war-problem